# What is the right way of testing a rails class method in the model, with RSpec & FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, tdd

I have to test a Category rails model, in isolation with rspec and factory girl. I start to define a category (record) with FactoryGirl like the following :

```
#spec/factories/category.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :category do |f|
    f.name "A/B Testing"
    f.tags_array %w(test a/b)
  end
end
```

and category model spec like :

```
# spec/models/category_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

  describe "Category" do
    before(:each) do
      @category = FactoryGirl.create(:category)
    end
    it "has a valid factory" do
      @category.should be_valid
    end
    it "is invalid without a name" do
      @category.name = nil
      @category.should_not be_valid
    end
    it "is invalid without at last one tag" do
      @category.tags_array = nil
      @category.should_not be_valid
    end
  end
```

Now I should define & test, a **Category class method** which return a **competitors** array of **Competitor** which is a Struct object, like the following:

```
  Object.const_set :Competitor, Struct.new(:html_url, :description, :watchers, :forks)
```

then this class method **seff.find_competitors_by_tags** should return an array of structs (array of :Competitor Struct objects):

```
  def self.find_competitors_by_tags(tags_array)
    competitors = []
    Extractor.each do |wl|
      competitors << Competitor.new(wl.html_url, wl.description, wl.watchers, wl.forks)
    end
    return competitors
  end
```

What's the best way to test this in isolation with RSpec & FactoryGirl? I thought something like the following but i can't say that clearly:

```
spec/factories/competitor.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :competitor do |f|
    f.html_url "https://github.com/assaf/vanity"
    f.description "Experiment Driven Development for Ruby"
    f.watchers "844"
    f.forks "146"
  end
end

# spec/models/category_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

  describe "Category" do
    ...
    ...

    it "returns a list of all competitors for each category" do
      competitors << FactoryGirl.create(:competitor) 
      competitors << Factory.build(:competitor, html_url: "https://github.com/andrew/split",
                                   description: "Rack Based AB testing framework",
                                   watchers: "357",
                                   forks: "42")
      @category.find_competitors_by_tags("A/B Testing").should == competitors
    end
  end
```

It doesn't work anyway and I'm also not sure if it is meaningful:

```
Failures:

      1) Category returns a list of all competitors for each category
         Failure/Error: @competitors << FactoryGirl.create(:competitor)
         NameError:
           uninitialized constant Competitor
         # ./spec/models/category_spec.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What is the right way of testing a method like this ?

Comment: You could post it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, there is not enough ruby/rails questions on there imho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked how you could test this in isolation:

```
 def self.find_competitors_by_tags(tags_array)
    competitors = []
    Extractor.each do |wl|
      competitors << Competitor.new(wl.html_url, wl.description, wl.watchers, wl.forks)
    end
    return competitors
  end
```

The main problem is the call to Extractor.each... You should send in the array to this method and invert this dependency. Any time your method is going out to get information on its own, that makes it hard to test. So something like this:

```
def self.find_competitors_by_tags(extractions, tags_array)
  extractions.map do |wl|
    Competitor.new(wl.html_url, wl.description, wl.watchers, wl.forks)
  end
end
```

Then you can easily send this and test it:

```
let(:extractions) {[ stub(:competitor), {html_url: "url", description: "description", watchers: "watchers", forks: "forks"] }

it "should map the extractions" do
  competitors = Class.find_competitors_by_tags(extractions, nil)
  competitors.first.html_url.should eq("url")
  #continue
end
```

Final note: `tags_array` seems unused.

Comment: thanks for great tips on inverting dependencies, anyway please consider last evolution of the class method, see UPDATE in the Q.

Comment: @LucaG.Soave The code seems to be getting more complex. You should be trying to make it simpler.